# Grafana: probes fail with relative path Ingress parameters

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, kubernetes-ingress

### Context

Say I have grafana exposed through the following **ingress**

```yaml
# Helm value file
grafana:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations: {}
    hosts:
      - host: chart-example.local
        paths: ["/grafana/"]
```

To overcome the *relative path issue* raised by this reverse proxy, I am using a useful mechanism I used several times: [grafana's docker image are entirely configurable with ENV VARS](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configure-docker/). Following [this doc](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1), I then wrote (not using variables yet):

```yaml
kind: Deployment
.....
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-grafana
          image: "{{ .Values.grafana.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.grafana.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          env:
          - name: GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL
            value: http://chart-example.local/grafana/
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
```

### Problem

Now readiness probes fail

> Readiness probe failed: Get "/grafana/login": stopped after 10 redirects Back-off restarting failed container

I don't quite understand why. I tried to change `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe`'s paths without much conviction: from the pod's stand point, routes are the same. I can for instance, with this configuration, access directly

```sh
http://${pods_ip}:3000/login
```

Why would it affect the **probes**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to **grafana.ini** `configMap` solved the probe issue

```
[server]
serve_from_sub_path = true
```